# jQuery not selecting element in template

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a template in my HTMl document that looks like below

```
<template id="attachment-template">
    <div class="mdl-grid mdl-grid--no-spacing attachment" data-file-type="" data-file-path="" data-file-name="" onclick="javascript:showAttachment($(this).data('file-path'), $(this).data('file-name'));">
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
            <div class="attachment-heading"></div>
            <div class="attachment-sub-heading"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I generate some content dynamically using this template and jQuery and create a list of `attachments`

When I am dynamically creating these elements, I need to set values in the data attributes. So I use the following jQuery code

```
var file_type_id = 5;
var filepath = '/some-path/to/filename.ext';
var filename = 'filename.ext';
var template = $($('#attachment-template').html().trim());
template.find('.attachment').data('file-type', file_type_id);
template.find('.attachment').data('file-path', filepath);
template.find('.attachment').data('file-name', filename);
```

However, template.find('.attachment') is returning a blank object. If I replace the same with the following code it at least prints the right element. What am I missing here? Why am I unable to select the parent element using a `finder`?

```
console.log(template[0]);
```

Comment: edited the code to replace `t` with the actual selector - essential `t` was a selector for the template

Comment: `showAttachment` what's that?

Comment: So which elements are supposed to get which data attributes? Your `template` variable is the problem, and it's unclear as to what elements should be modified, as well as what `file_type_id`, `filepath`, and `filename` refer to.

Comment: `showAttachment` is a javascript function that takes values set in the data attributes and processes some on-screen function

Comment: @j08691 - edited the question to clarify the variables

Answer (score 1):

It's because there:

```
var template = $($('#attachment-template').html().trim());
```

you get the *inner* html. And `find` method searches in *inner* html too.
So your `template` var is equal to:

```
<div class="mdl-grid mdl-grid--no-spacing attachment" data-file-type="" data-file-path="" data-file-name="" onclick="javascript:showAttachment($(this).data('file-path'), $(this).data('file-name'));">
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
            <div class="attachment-heading"></div>
            <div class="attachment-sub-heading"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and you searches through those elements:

```
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
    <div class="attachment-heading"></div>
    <div class="attachment-sub-heading"></div>
</div>
```

and of course you don't find anything. The bug is in the first line, you should replace it with:

```
var template = $('#attachment-template');
```

Comment: Tim - you were almost there. Yes, you were right, by using `.html().trim()` I didnt have access to the `find` element. So I just removed `find` and used this statement - `template.data('file-path`, filepath)` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap template with div.

```
var file_type_id = 5;
var filepath = '/some-path/to/filename.ext';
var filename = 'filename.ext';
var template = $($('#attachment-template').html().trim());
var div = $('<div></div>').html(template);
var attachment = div.find('.attachment');
attachment.data('file-type', file_type_id);
attachment.data('file-path', filepath);
attachment.data('file-name', filename);
```